# Checkboxes working like radio button, but how to uncheck?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

```
<div id="checkboxes">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="box1" value="orange" class="btn"> Oranges</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="box2" value="apple" class="btn"> Apples</label>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function()
{
    jQuery(document).on("change", ".btn", function()
    {
        jQuery(".btn").prop("checked", false);

        if (! this.checked)
            jQuery(this).prop("checked", true);
    });
});
</script>
```

This works great to make checkboxes behave like radio buttons, but "unchecking" does not work. How to allow users to be able to uncheck as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get that behaviour by default. All the JS needs to do in this case is to uncheck every `.btn` element except the one which raised the event:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $(document).on("change", ".btn", function() {
    $(".btn").not(this).prop("checked", false);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="checkboxes">
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="box1" value="orange" class="btn"> Oranges</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="box2" value="apple" class="btn"> Apples</label>
</div>
```